# hide or delete image src=undefined

Tags: javascript, image, undefined, src

I'm working with markers on google map and this is what happens

I call this variable to the images and upload to the database and use a query to put two images into a single file (GROUP_CONCAT)

```
var image = markers[i].getAttribute("image");
image = image.split(",");
```

And here I show these pictures.

```
var html = div id = "iw-container" +

'a Href="'+image[0]+'" data-lightbox="roadtrip" <img src = "' + image [0] +" "width = 100" height = "100" / a  '+

'a Href="'+image[1]+'" data-lightbox="roadtrip" <img src = "' + image [1] + '" width = 100 "height =" 100 " / a  '+

'a Href="'+image[2]+'" data-lightbox="roadtrip" <img src = "' + image [2] + '" width = 100 "height =" 100 " / a  '+

'/ Div';
```

The problem is if a marker is less than 3 images, for example a marker has 2 images, one of the images appear broken. obviously because not defined. ()

I wonder if there is any function or something to check if an image has the "SRC" undefined, remove it or hide it or do something to not appear.

Any help is good, thanks :)

Comment: Do you have any code attempting to do what you're asking for?

Comment: Looks like you need to learn about the `for` loop

Comment: i dont want a for what I need is to hide or remove the images that are like "src undefined". There is something to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Code like this should get you past this issue:

```
var html = '';
for(var i=0;i < image.length; i++) {
  html += image[i];
}
```

Comment: i dont want a for 

what I need is to hide or remove the images that are like "src undefined".

There is something to do that?

Comment: The middle statement of the `for` loop is a test for how many times to loop (the length of the `image` array). If the array has a length of 3 but with elements that are `undefined` you could add an inner `if(image[i]) {}` to only append to the `html` when the array element isn't undefined (or the Boolean value `false`)